# Slow converging in Monte Carlo due to Shell effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

While I was reading materials, the author mentioned that Monte Carlo converges slowly due to shell effect while filling the single particle states, but using a twisted boundary will make it go much faster.

I am wondering why is shell effect causing this issue, I have never done computation physics but intrigued by this problem.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You'd better provided the link to the reference

Comment: what if i dont?

Comment: it would be easier for the audience to have a look and answer your question